# RFM Segmentation Excel Take Mid Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to segment Customer with RFM Segmentation ranged 1 to 5 for each column R, F and M. After I combined the three column, there are many possibilities such as `151`, `555`, or `254` and so on.
Code `555` is the best Customer
and `X5X` is the loyal customer. "X" defines any numbers, e.g Code `454` is also Loyal Customer segmentation.
The problem is i cannot exactly deliver the IF function in excel correctly. Here is my trial for `555`

```
=IF(O14="555","Best Customer",IF(MID(O14,2,1)="5","Loyal Customer"))
```

The function overlaps since it took the latest IF, so the result for `555` is Loyal Customer which should be Best Customer. There are many segmentation such as `XX5` for the big spenders, however since the formula turns to overlap i cannot continue the rest. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want 1 result per number, then you just need to put the highest priority first. The first IF that is TRUE will be the one that is used. From your example, it looks like "455" would be both a Loyal Customer and a Big Spender. We can't tell from your explanation what the result should be in this case. But whichever is the higher priority should just come earlier in your nested IF statements.

Your formula looks correct that 555 should return "Best Customer". If it is returning Loyal Customer, then it seems like you've got 555 stored as a number rather than text in O14. If it is a number, your formula should instead be:

```
=IF(O14=555,"Best Customer",IF(MID(O14,2,1)="5","Loyal Customer"))
```

The only difference is removing the quotes around 555. If O14 is stored as a number, then O14="555" is comparing a number to a string (three "5" characters rather than the number 555), which will always return FALSE, hence it moves on the next IF statement. To get a TRUE result at the start, you need to compare O14 to the number 555 instead.

You may then be confused about why the 2nd part of the formula works. This is because the MID function will accept a number as input and then force a type conversion.

When you use the = operator, excel can only compare like values. Meaning it can compare strings to strings or numbers to numbers, but not strings to numbers.

However, the MID function will accept either strings or numbers. When it is given a number, it will first convert it to a string and then output a string.

If it is given MID(555,2,1), it first changes 555 to "555" and gives the same result as MID("555",2,1), which is the character "5" rather than the number 5.

So, even if O14 has the number 555, MID(014,2,1) will return the character "5" and the comparison MID(O14,2,1)="5" will return TRUE.